# Timer circuit does not work as intended (fixed)

Tags: timer, crystal, diy

I am trying to make a 1 Hz clock with a CD4060, a crystal oscillator and an Arduino UNO.
The problem is I am pretty sure the circuit does not work right. It oscillates but it is slower than 1 Hz.

I don't have right now any way to make timing measurement (I try to avoid making one I just compare the serial output of Arduino by looking to windows clock). I would be happy with something that counts seconds with a small error.

The circuit oscillates if I take out the 470k resistor which means it does not use the crystal...
The 4060 contains an internal oscillator, how to disable it?
Any information would be appreciated.

EDIT:

The circuit in my case worked with the following values (in contrast with the values mentioned on the old or the newer datasheet):

both capacitors 100pF
The capacitor on the (11) pin connected with some wire to add some capacitance.

Resistor 11-10 -> 1M

Second resistor 300k

corrected circuit:

[image]

Arduino divide by two, counting seconds and measuring period:

[image]

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

```
#include "printf_function.h"

#pragma GCC optimize ("Os")

bool state = false; 
uint8_t seconds = 0;
uint32_t time_stamp = 0;
uint32_t PreviousMillis = 0;
uint32_t m_i = 0;

void blink(){ 

    state = !state; 

    if( state ){
        m_i = millis();
        time_stamp = m_i - PreviousMillis; 
        PreviousMillis = m_i; 
        serial_printf( Serial, "%i   %i\n", seconds, time_stamp );
        if( seconds++ > 58 ) seconds = 0;
    }

}

void setup(){

    pinMode( 2, INPUT );
    pinMode( 13, OUTPUT );
    digitalWrite( 13, LOW );
    Serial.begin( 9600 );
    attachInterrupt( digitalPinToInterrupt( 2 ), blink, RISING );

} 

void loop(){ } 


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add a schematic. The PCB layout doesn't cut it as a circuit diagram.

Comment: Well, you need a 32.768kHz crystal to make an oscillator and count it down to 1Hz. Ref: CD4060 14 stage Binary Counter and Oscillator - TI
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4060b.pdf

Comment: Why do you think it's unnecessary...how can others find a circuit fault in a circuit they can't see?

Comment: @John Am: This new datasheet explains how to use an external clock input at terminal RS: 
CD4060 14 stage Binary Counter and Oscillator - NXP 2021 
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF4060B.pdf NXP2021

Comment: @tlfong01 Thank you

Comment: Are you using a breadboard? Than capacitances are just a question of good luck or bad luck. Breadboards have relatively high internal capacitances (that's why you often get away without blocking capacitors close to the IC.. but you should never rely on that!)

Comment: @kruemi Yes It's on the breadboard. I haven't used bypass capacitors on the IC

Comment: Ok... make it a habit to use a bypass capacitor on every IC. It will save you a lot of searching for hard to track intermittent problems in the future... If you solved the issue, write your solution as an answer and accept that answer so others with the same problem can find it.